# TwitterBootStrap Submit Button still submits the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following Bootstrap submit button with an onclick function.

```
@Html.Bootstrap().SubmitButton().Text("Submit Final").Id("btnSubmitBottom").Style(ButtonStyle.Primary).HtmlAttributes(new { onclick = "return SubmitCheck('Submit Final')", name = "command", value = "Submit Final" }).Disabled(blnButtonsDisabled)
```

SubmitCheck has this ajax code that calls another function and returns a text value.  Based off of that value I display a confirm box (true) to the user or a Bootbox modal(false).

```
               $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "professionalismSubmitFinal",
                    data: { teacherID: CurrentTeacherID },
                    dataType: "text",
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    },
                    success: function (textVal) {
                        if (textVal == 'True') {
                            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to submit this as final?")) {
                                $('#IsPublic').val(true);
                                $('#IsFinal').val(true);
                                submitFormOkay = true;
                                return true;
                            }
                            else {
                                $('#IsFinal').val(false);
                                return false;
                            } //cancelled from modal
                        } else {
                            bootbox.alert("You cannot Submit until this has been Submitted as Final.");
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
```

The problem is when the Ajax call returns 'False' the bootbox alert displays correctly but then the form also submits.

What am I doing incorrectly?  I thought the `onclick = return SubmitCheck` would prevent this behavior?

Comment: Your `return` statements are returning from the anonymous `success` callback function, not from `SubmitCheck()`. You'll need to prevent the default action of the form, wait for the ajax call to complete, then resubmit the form, maybe after removing the handler or setting some flag to let the submit go through.

Comment: @JasonP - Do you have an example that you can show me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe `event.preventDefault();` on the button click event will help you

```
$("#yourButton").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Hope I understood your problem correctly.

Comment: So if it passes all of my checks then how do I submit the form?